# how to create the timers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbmc

I'm working on my python script as I want to set up the timers in every 2 seconds to allow me to update the values in the setLabel function. I need to create the timers with each different values for setLabel, because they are only allow me to update it once at a time.

Here is for example:

```
#set the timer for 2 seconds to update the value in the setlabel
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("1%")


#Stop the timer and set the timer again for 2 seconds
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("8%")


#Stop the timer and set the timer again for another 2 seconds
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("16%")
```

and so on...

Can you please tell me how I can create the timers to allow me to update the values in each at a time?

**Edit: When I try this:**

```
# Get the loaded data
                         for channel in tv_elem.findall('channel'):
                             channel_name = 
channel.find('display-name').text
                             for program in channel.findall('programme'):
                                 title = program.find('title').text
                                 start_time = program.get("start")
                                 stop_time = program.get("stop")
                                 cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, 
title, start_date, stop_date)" + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, 
title, start_time, stop_time])
                                 con.commit()
                                 con.close

                                 time.sleep(2)
                                 #Stop the timer and set the timer again 
for 2 seconds
                                 self.getControl(4202).setLabel("8%")

                                 time.sleep(2)
                                 #Stop the timer and set the timer again 
for another 2 seconds
                                 self.getControl(4202).setLabel("16%")

                                 time.sleep(2)
                                 #Stop the timer and set the timer again 
for another 2 seconds
                                 self.getControl(4202).setLabel("24%")
```

It will not let me to write the data in a database. Any idea?

Comment: does anyone know how??????????

Comment: What does it mean "not let me"? Error? Exception? From the code it's strange that you call con.close() in the loop. You may want to open/close before/after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `sleep` from the `time` module?

```
import time

time.sleep(2) # probably don't need this one
#set the timer for 2 seconds to update the value in the setlabel
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("1%")


time.sleep(2)
#Stop the timer and set the timer again for 2 seconds
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("8%")


time.sleep(2)
#Stop the timer and set the timer again for another 2 seconds
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("16%")
```

Comment: thank you very much, I can see it is working right now. How I can use these code to work with when I'm storing the data in a sqlite3 database? when I try those code under the database, it make things stop working. Any idea?

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer. When I try the code you post, it will not let me to write the data in a database. When I get rid of these code of `time.sleep(5)`, it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: You probably need to figure out how to group your transactions into a single transaction, using sleep() in this manner is probably just a bad workaround. It's starting to look like you didn't ask a very clear question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Python scheduling libraries to choose from. Celery is an extremely robust synchronous task queue and message system that supports scheduled tasks.

Have you tried Advanced Python Scheduler (APScheduler)
I like it. You can call functions

```
@sched.interval_schedule(minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    print 'This job is run every three minutes.'
```